# WPF Make layout dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make layout dynamically.

For example, When I drag and drop a image, 1 image appears on the box.

When I drag and drop another image, box divide into 2 box (dynamically divide into two).

My question is, what layout should I use (stack panel, grid, or something else) and How to I make layout dynamically using code?

I know question is a little vague but I'm not so good at WPF so please understand Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a GridView and so you can add column or row.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn trackPositionTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
trackPositionTextBox.HeaderText = "Track Postion";
trackPositionTextBox.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

dataGridViewSamples.Columns.Add(trackPositionTextBox);
```

That's to add a Column in a DataGridView.

```
dataGridViewSamples.Row.Add()
```

That's to add a row.

I'm also not the best in wpf, but I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any animation, you could simple add new columns and rows to your WPF-Grid, while drop an image.

Maybe this help you: [How to add rows and columns to a WPF Grid programmatically](http://deepak-sharma.net/2013/02/01/how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-wpf-grid-programmatically/)